# How to adjust scrollview height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm having troubles with UIScrollView using auto layout constraints. I have the following view hierarchy

```
-view
  -scrollView
    -view A
    -view B
```

In View, A or View B inside content are increased according to receive a response. So please help me how to set the scroll view height according to content.

Comment: tableView is best option rather then scrollview.

Comment: Are you sure about scrollView _height_? Maybe you need to update its `contentSize`?

Comment: make a autolayout constraint to top, bottom, left and right and a centre alignment of the screen

Comment: yes, I am sure about scroll view height.I also update its content size if  I update its height then show space in the bottom.

Comment: I also create the autolayout constraint to top, bottom, left and right and a centre alignment of the screen @AnilKumar

Comment: is it working fine now..? if not add a screen shot of the constraints you have added

Comment: Are you sure about scrollview height and not a content size? if that so then you can use stack view instead of scrollview with distribution fill.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with autolayout, you need to set constraints on:

```
- viewA.top = scrollView.top
- viewA.height = 100 (or make the view autosizing the same way as scrollview)
- viewB.top = viewA.bottom
- viewB.height = 100 (or make the view autosizing the same way as scrollview)
- viewB.bottom = scrollView.bottom
```

This will allow you to make scrollview adopting to the content size.
Now you need to set constraints for scrollview on parent view.

```
- scrollView.top = view.top + 100 (just an example)
```

The most important for you is have constraints between all the subviews in scrollview plus first one need to have top constraint to top of the scrollview and the last one has to be connected to bottom of the scrollview.

That rule applies to all views, that you want to have "autosizing" height - for example autosizing `UITableViewCell`s

Answer (score 0):

Working with scrollView in IB you must set constraints for ViewA & ViewB height. If you don't set the scrollView can't set his height.

And you must set the constrains for the scrollview margins to superview.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple developer about Auto Layout Guide, there is a part name "Working with Scroll Views" has a clear solution for your problem

> For most common layout tasks, the logic becomes far easier if you use
>   a dummy view or layout group to contain the scroll view’s content.
>   When working in Interface Builder, the general approach is shown
>   below:
>
> 1. Add the scroll view to the scene.
> 2. Draw constraints to define the
>      scroll view’s size and position, as normal.
> 3. Add a view to the scroll
>      view. Set the view’s Xcode specific label to Content View.
> 4. Pin the content view’s top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges to the scroll
>      view’s corresponding edges. The content view now defines the scroll
>      view’s content area.
> 5. (Optional) To disable horizontal scrolling, set the content view’s width equal to the scroll view’s width. The content view now fills the scroll view horizontally.
> 6. (Optional) To disable vertical scrolling, set the content view’s height equal to the scroll view’s height. The content view now fills the scroll view horizontally.
> 7. Lay out the scroll view’s content inside the content view. Use constraints to position the content inside the content view as normal.

**Another important things when do auto layout by code is to 
disable translation from auto resizing mask to constraint by this code:**

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

So your view hierarchy is:

```
-view
  -scrollView
    -scrollContentView
      -view A
      -view B
```

Constraint for scrollView is like a normal view, for example you want your scrollView take all space in its parent view.

```
[scrollView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.leadingAnchor];
[scrollView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.trailingAnchor];
[scrollView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.topAnchor];
[scrollView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.bottomAnchor];
```

And similar to scrollContentView

```
[scrollContentView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollView.leadingAnchor];
[scrollContentView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollView.trailingAnchor];
[scrollContentView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollView.topAnchor];
[scrollContentView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollView.bottomAnchor];
```

And finally is constraints for viewA and viewB, set viewA's bottom pin to viewB's top

```
[viewA.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollContentView.leadingAnchor];
[viewA.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollContentView.trailingAnchor];
[viewA.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollContentView.topAnchor];
[viewA.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: viewB.topAnchor];

[viewB.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollContentView.leadingAnchor];
[viewB.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollContentView.trailingAnchor];
[viewB.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: viewA.bottomAnchor];
[viewB.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: scrollContentView.topAnchor];
```